# NameError: name 'edit' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I am trying to let the user say which command they would like to use but when I type something in for the input in the console like 'edit', it says,

> inputr=str(input("new_employee, id_search, edit, pay_calc"))
>   File "", line 1, in
>
> NameError: name 'edit' is not defined

even though 'edit' is not a variable, but a string. I am checking to see if the person types edit then, if so, run `edit_employee()`

Here is my code:

```
name=[]    
hours=[]    
payrate=[]

def new_employee():
    employeenum=input("How many new employees?")
    for i in range(employeenum):
        emname=input("Enter the name of employee "+str(i)+'...')
        empayrate=input("Enter the payrate per hour of employee "+str(i)+'...')
        name.insert(i,emname)
        hours.insert(i,emhours)    

def employee_python_id_search():
    search=lower(input("Enter name of employee to search..."))
    for i in range(name):
        if search==name[i]:
            print(name,':',str(i))            

def edit_employee():
    editnum=input("Enter employee python id number")
    empayrate=input("Enter the payrate per hour of employee "+str(i)+'...')
    payrate.append(editnum)    

def pay_calculator():
    search=lower(input("Enter name of employee to search..."))
    emhours=input("Enter the hours worked of employee "+str(i)+'...')
    for i in range(name):
        if search==name[i]:
            print(name[i],'made',str(payrate[i]))

inputr=str(input("new_employee, id_search, edit, pay_calc"))

def checknew():
    if inputr=="new_employee":
        new_employee()

def checkid():
    if inputr=="id_search":
        employee_python_id_search()

def checkedit():
    if inputr=="edit":
        edit_employee()

def checkcalc():
    if inputr=="pay_calc":
        pay_calculator()

def check():
    checknew()
    checkid()
    checkedit()
    checkcalc()

check()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are running this Python 3.x script with Python 2.x, and the `input()` method is not being interpreted correctly. [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in a Python 2.x context actually evaluates the user's input as Python code, rather than saving that input as a string. So if you have `foo = input()`, and type `1 + 1`, `foo` will be set equal to the integer `2` rather than the string `'1 + 1'`. In your case, instead of returning `'edit'`, it is trying to evaluate the variable name `edit`, which you have not defined.

To solve this, make sure to run your script with Python 3:

```
$ python3 my_script.py
```

Or, on the off chance that you actually want to use Python 2; [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) provides the same functionality as `input()` does in Python 3.

Also, one other thing that pops out: `edit_employee()` will raise an exception because you have not defined `i`. Instead, you probably want to use `editnum` in its place here. You also probably want to append the `empayrate` to the `payrate` list, not the `editnum`:

```
def edit_employee():
    editnum=input("Enter employee python id number")
    empayrate=input("Enter the payrate per hour of employee "+str(editnum)+'...')
    payrate.append(empayrate)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped

Comment: @IAmADoctorYes, great! Don't forget to accept the answer in that case ;)